# Getting Frame for CAGradientLayer from CAShapeLayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation, cashapelayer, cagradientlayer

I have a custom CAShapeLayer class and there I am drawing a circular image using “ bezierPathWithArcCenter ”  with some stroke color. That works fine and I am getting a circular image. Now to add a gradient to this. I have add the below lines

```
_gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
_gradient.colors = @[(id)[UIColor greenColor].CGColor,
                    (id)[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.90 alpha:1.0].CGColor];
_gradient.frame = CGPathGetBoundingBox(_progressLayer.path);
```

Where _gradient.frame = CGPathGetBoundingBox(self.path) always returns 0.

Where am I making the mistake??

I want view like below

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that the progress layer has a frame or a path?

Comment: Yes, it has a valid path to draw.

Comment: @manoj u solved this problem?

Comment: Hi @Lea-rner.. I solved it but am not sure whether my approach is right. So I have not posted the answer yet.

Comment: posted it in comment then